# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Manager Works Briefly After Reboot

Tags: workflow-manager

I've got a standalone WFM for SharePoint 2013.  Up to CU 4.

Working just fine previously, but just yesterday out of the blue, they all stopped working.  They would only briefly work after a WFM server reboot and then they just stop again.  No errors in SP logs, no events in the Event log, nothing to see in the WF or SB event logs.  All the services are up and running.  No changes to the WFM recently.  At a complete loss.  Anyone have any troubleshooting tips or ideas?

I suppose next I was thinking about removing from the SB & WF Farm and rejoining, but wanted to avoid that at the moment.

Comment: While not likely to resolve it, have you deployed WFM CU5?

Comment: I was waiting because a prereq was SQL 2012 SP4, so only got to CU4.

Comment: did you check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193526%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193529(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Yes I have.  Unfortunately nothing there has been helpful with this except a server reboot, but that is only a brief solution.

Comment: I removed from the farm and rejoined and that still didn't fix this.  Dang.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like your WFM farm is working fine. Have you checked the 'connection' to SharePoint?

I would check the following things:

- Workflow service application is online (Central Admin or PowerShell)
- Workflow service application is connected to respective Web application via a service application connection group (Central Admin or PowerShell)
- Re-publish one of the workflows (SharePoint Designer, CSOM or PowerShell)

Comment: Workflow Service Application was/is online and connected.   
Workflow Service Application was/is added to the service application group  
I backed up, deleted a WF, re-imported it, tested again but still no dice.  It should start on item created, but it's not even doing that.  If I start it manually, it "starts" as Initiator = Anonymous and Status = Not Started.  
  
It does seem like it is working fine and there is nothing being written/reported that says it's not.  The workflows just won't run.   Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to open a ticket with Microsoft.  What we did, which was kinda where I was going to go anyways, was:

- Leave the farm
- Uninstall worklfow manager and service bus and all updates
- Remove any directories where they were installed
- Install WFM 1.0 CU2 Refresh
- Install WFM CU5 (latest CU)